# How to submit ASP NET MVC3 Form through ajax while overriding default behavior while maintaining client side validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to be able to post this form data using an ajax post, but I cannot figure out how to override the default behavior when the form is posted. I still want client side validation from ASP NET MVC3 though. For example, when I click "submit" in this form, it goes directly to the controller action when I have a jquery function that is supposed to directly handle any submit from this form.

```
 @model BlogApp.Models.PostUser

 @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "testform" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { id = "Name" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</fieldset>
}
```

this is the jquery function:

```
 $('#testform').live('submit', function () {
    $('#testform').validate();

    var name = $('#Name').val();
    var logout = '<a href="#" onClick="logOut()">logout</a>';
    var login_success = '<p>Logged in as: ' + name + '</p>' + logout;

    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/loginform',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { name: name },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === true) {
                    $('#loginform').empty();
                    $('#loginform').append(login_success);
                }
                else {
                    alert('Failed to save the user');
                }
            }
        });
    }


});
```

So my question is: instead of the form automatically going to the controller action (/Home/LoginForm/) and returning that result, how can I make submitting the form fire my jquery function (so that the page doesn't auto-refresh), but still maintaining the client side validation?

Answer (score 1):

The `<input type="submit" value="submit" />` is probably the culprit. The default form submission is occurring because of the input type submit. You could change your submit button to be a different html tag (like a span) and then use JQuery to assign the click event to handle your submission, or you could cancel the default action within your submit handler you have now (see the [.submit() documentation for JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) on how to do that).

> ...we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from our handler